# How to include HTML template into a selected document

Tags: html, css

I have created few templates which will be used within my design. For example nodes at the adjacent trunks at the same level with have the same layout/navigation bar, but additional content will differ. Templates are rough and need much more work, I will surely return to them in the future to modify them. In the meantime I will work on other elements of on each pages that is unique to each one.

How do I include given template for example `sub_folder_temp.html` in every element I want it to. I know that I could copy and paste it at the beginning of the HTML file or write a script that does it. Is there any command that would allow to import HTML template or how else do I go about including it?

Thanks

Sorry if I am not being very clear, quite new to this. Slightly difficult to express exactly what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score 1):

Create new file called `header.php` for example, include all what is needed in here, then in file you want use it in, do like this:

```
<?php require_once 'header.php'; ?>
```

Then you can just type content and header will stay the same. You can obviously do same thing with footer.